# How to pass in a specific country for billing/shipping?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to work out how you can pass along a pre-defined country for the billing/shipping address on **Stripe JS** ( https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js )

Here is what I have, and it works:

```
handler.open({
      name: 'My Company',
      description: "Your Order",
      currency: window.my_config.currency,
      amount: amount * 100,
      email: $('#Email').val(),
      billingAddress: true,
      shippingAddress: true
    });
```

However, it lets them change their country code (not something I want, as it means they would set their country to a cheap level shipping zone, and then change it in the actual payment).

Is this even possible? Or would I have to collect and create the shipping address myself, to be able to get around? I was hoping you could just pass in something like:

```
countryCode: "US"
```

or

```
country: "US"
```

... and that would force it to keep that value in the shipping/billing address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to pre-fill any of [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout)'s fields other than the email address (via the `data-email` / `email` [configuration option](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional)).

You'd either need to collect the address separately (outside of Checkout), or replace Checkout entirely with your own custom form, using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) instead.

Comment: Ah ok - I had a feeling that may be the case. In that case, seeing as we are the ones who will be completing the orders, I'm just going to leave it to be set by the client. We will check the orders before sending, so any "cheaters" will be found out :)